# Web API Routing - No action was found on the controller that matches the request

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Ok web api routing fun.

my web api route config is below. the geocoding and info routes are performing great. And I'm confused why the search one is not following suite.

```cs
/*
    ==Geocoding Endpoints==
*/

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "v1_GeocodeApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/{controller}/{street}/{zone}",
    defaults: new
    {
        action = "get",
        controller = "Geocode",
        version = "1"
    });

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "v1_GeocodeMultipleApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/{controller}/multiple",
    defaults: new
    {
        action = "multiple",
        controller = "Geocode",
        version = "1"
    }); 

/*
    ==Search Endpoints==
*/

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "v1_SearchApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/{controller}/{featureClass}/{returnValues}",
    defaults: new
    {
        action = "Get",
        controller = "Search",
        version = "1"
    });

/*
    ==Info Endpoints==
*/

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "v1_InfoApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/{controller}/FeatureClassNames",
    defaults: new
    {
        action = "FeatureClassNames",
        controller = "Info",
        version = "1"
    });
}
```

so i want to have a url like `http://webapi/api/v1/search/fc/rv`. This url produces the below stack trace and resulting 404. I thought the convention was that if you had a controller with a get method it would be used by default. That seems to be what happens with the first geocoding route.

```
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET,
Url=http://webapi/api/v1/Search/fc/rv,
Message='http://webapi/api/v1/Search/fc/rv'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Search',
Operation=RouteVersionedControllerSelector.SelectController w3wp.exe
Information: 0 :
Message='WebAPI.API.Controllers.API.Version1.SearchController',
Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create w3wp.exe Information:
0 : Message='WebAPI.API.Controllers.API.Version1.SearchController',
Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController w3wp.exe
Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonpMediaTypeFormatter'
formatter',
Operation=JsonpMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected
formatter='JsonpMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json;
charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate w3wp.exe
Warning: 0 : Message='UserMessage='No HTTP resource was found that
matches the request URI
'http://webapi/api/v1/Search/fc/rv'.',
MessageDetail='No action was found on the controller 'Search' that
matches the request.'',
Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction, Status=404
(NotFound), Exception=System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException:
Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see
the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this
exception for details.    at
System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
controllerContext)    at
System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionSelectorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction>b__0()    at
System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter
traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel
level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace,
Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace) w3wp.exe
Warning: 0 : Message='UserMessage='No HTTP resource was found that
matches the request URI
'http://webapi/api/v1/Search/fc/rv'.',
MessageDetail='No action was found on the controller 'Search' that
matches the request.'', Operation=SearchController.ExecuteAsync,
Status=404 (NotFound),
Exception=System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException: Processing of the
HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response
returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.   
at
System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
controllerContext)    at
System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionSelectorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction>b__0()    at
System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter
traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel
level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace,
Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)    at
System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionSelectorTracer.System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
controllerContext)    at
System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController.ExecuteAsync>b__0()
at
System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEndAsync[TResult](ITraceWriter
traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel
level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace,
Func`1 execute, Action`2 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace) w3wp.exe
Information: 0 : Response, Status=404 (NotFound), Method=GET,
Url=http://webapi/api/v1/Search/fc/rv,
Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8',
content-length=unknown'
```

Now if I were to make another route more similar to the second geocoding route with the /multiple making the route template `api/v{version}/{controller}/**for**/{featureClass}/{returnValues}` the routing works and all is happy.

The controller signature is

```cs
public class SearchController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string featureClass, string returnValues, [FromUri] SearchOptions options)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My hunch is that the async Task part is throwing it off somehow with the default get binding but that doesn't make sense since it works with the modified route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request url `http://webapi/api/v1/search/fc/rv` is matching the `v1_GeocodeApi` route which has the 'stree' and 'zone' variables. Since these variable names do not match the Search controller's Get method's parameter names, you are seeing 404. You can try modifying your routes to not accept the controller name as variable, but have something like `api/v{version}/Geocode/{street}/{zone}`, `api/v{version}/Search/{featureClass}/{returnValues}`

Comment: I would say that is incorrect since the stack trace says it chooses WebAPI.API.Controllers.API.Version1.SearchController. but modifying the routes to remove the {conroller} does fix the issue.

Comment: I am a bit unclear by your comment...which is incorrect here?

Comment: i wrote that before your edit. i didn't think the v1_geocodeapi route was being selected because of the text in the stack trace. but it makes sense now since the 404 is usually thrown when parameter names don't match. which is exactly what was happening. I wish the trace would display the chosen route. i think there are other projects for doing that.